# EXCEL removing letters in end of LSKU

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

`LSKU:000AD21961PD`, `000BP20725PA`, `00C0BC23057C`

I need to make them to `:000AD21961`, `000BP20725`, `00C0BC23057` without alphabet in the end of LSKU. I tried using this formula:
 `SUBSTITUTE(A7,IF(RIGHT(A7,1)="C","C"),"!").`

However, it replaces 00C0B!23057! for third LSKU. I planned to remove all !.

Comment: Is `000AD21961PD, 000BP20725PA, 00C0BC23057C` in a single cell??

Comment: How your data is places in sheet?

Comment: each cell. so, A1=000AD21961PD, A2=000BP20725PA, A3=00C0BC23057C

Comment: and I would like to make it to C1=000AD21961, C2=000BP20725, C3=00C0BC23057

Answer (score 1):

```
{=left(A2,MAX(if(isnumber(--mid(A2,row($1:$99),1)),row($1:$99))))}
```

This formula will be helpful for any length of suffix letters. The outer {} is produced by Ctrl+Shift+Enter （key combination press)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, if the last character is a 'C', you want to drop it altogether correct?

Then this should work:

=IF(RIGHT(A7,1)="C",LEFT(A7,LEN(A7)-1),A7)